# Service Broker : An error occurred while receiving data: '10054(An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

I have executed service broker within same instances with success. But recently I started exploring Distributed Service broker application between multiple instances without any success.

I have created two instances(both are Developer Editions) in two different systems within my domain, when I send a message from one instance to another, its not sending to receiving/target instance.  When I check `sys.transmission_queue`, I get `transmission_status` as below:

```
An error occurred while receiving data: 
'10054(An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)'.
```

Comment: Sandeep, did you resolve this? I am also facing same issue. Please update question with solution

Answer (score 1):

Attach Profiler to the *other* instance (the one that is closing the connection 'forcibly') and monitor for the [Audit Broker Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190261.aspx) class. It will trace the reason why it refuses the connection (most likely CONNECT permission is missing on the endpoint).

Also running [`ssbdiagnose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934450.aspx) should reveal the issue:

```
ssbdiagnose runtime connect to -S <machineA> connect to -S <machineB>
```